# Float index in Mid function MS Access

Tags: ms-access

```
Mid([table1]![field1], 2.9)
```

I've found this operation in an old Access file someone made and is still being used. Who can explain that 2.9? My research says that parameter should be a natural number as it is the starting index of string [field1], isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odds are that's a typo and it's supposed to be `Mid([table1]![field1], 2,9)`

Indeed, it's supposed to be a whole number, but since it isn't, it's cast to a whole number. 2.9 is rounded up, becomes 3, and the thing works fine. This means it won't cause an error, it just might cause unexpected results if you expect the maximum length returned to be 9 characters.

Comment: What I see in the rest of the queries is that it is intended to get the string from 3rd position, so should be `Mid([table1]![field1], 3)`... Is there any technical reason to write 2.9 instead of 3? (like exploding some sort of low level special behavior)

Comment: Nope, it's just cast to a 3 immediately. There's no possible reason for it, no other behavior than putting a 3 there, except if you want your code to perform a tiny bit worse (since there's overhead from casting 2.9 to 3, but that's barely measurable.